# group by id final result in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

currently i am getting below response

```
[
    {
        "_id": "89787517-0085-3a0a-7232-1105457d6075",
        "totalStoriesPlanned": 2,
        "storiesWithDependencies": 0,
        "plannedVelocity": null,
        "actualVelocity": 0,
        "businessValue": 0,
        "sprintType": "Dev",
        "storyData": [],
        "teamExternalId": "b663fa97-22fa-44b9-b845-22a57d408550"
    }
{
        "_id": "12347517-0085-3a0a-7232-1105457d6075",
        "totalStoriesPlanned": 2,
        "storiesWithDependencies": 0,
        "plannedVelocity": null,
        "actualVelocity": 0,
        "businessValue": 0,
        "sprintType": "Dev",
        "storyData": [],
        "teamExternalId": "b663fa97-22fa-44b9-b845-22a57d408550"
    }

]
```

i want response like below. group by `teamExternalId`:

```
{
   "teamExternalId": "b663fa97-22fa-44b9-b845-22a57d408550",
   "insight":[
    {
        "_id": "89787517-0085-3a0a-7232-1105457d6075",
        "totalStoriesPlanned": 2,
        "storiesWithDependencies": 0,
        "plannedVelocity": null,
        "actualVelocity": 0,
        "businessValue": 0,
        "sprintType": "Dev",
        "storyData": [],
        "teamExternalId": "b663fa97-22fa-44b9-b845-22a57d408550"
    },
{
        "_id": "12347517-0085-3a0a-7232-1105457d6075",
        "totalStoriesPlanned": 2,
        "storiesWithDependencies": 0,
        "plannedVelocity": null,
        "actualVelocity": 0,
        "businessValue": 0,
        "sprintType": "Dev",
        "storyData": [],
        "teamExternalId": "b663fa97-22fa-44b9-b845-22a57d408550"
    }


]


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

- `group` - to group documents by **teamExternalId** field
- `project` - to project fields in requested format

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$teamExternalId",
      "insight": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "teamExternalId": "$_id",
      "_id": 0,
      "insight": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GLTZT5qyIhU)

Comment: getting only one record if i gave 3 teamExternalId